# Disabling a particular date in uidatepicker in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5

Is there any way to  disable a particular date in uidatepicker ?

Comment: No. You can specify a minimum & maximum date, but not an unselrcta me date

Answer (score 2):

Since there is not direct method to implement this, what you can do is get the "UIControlEventValueChanged" from datePicker like

```
UIDatePicker * datePick = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
[datePick addTarget:self action:@selector(disableDate) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

In disableDate method, the user can check if the current date is equal to the disableDate.If yes, then he can set the currentDate to some previous date.

```
-(void)disableDate{

    NSDate *pickedDate = datePicker.date;  // Get current Date
    NSDate *disabledDate = [self getDisabledDate] // Returns Disabled Date.(getDisabledDate returns a date to be diabled).
    if([pickedDate compare:disabledDate] == NSOrderedSame){
        [datePick setDate:[self someOtherDate] animated:YES];
```

// Set current Date to some other date(someOtherDate methos returns a date to be set ,if disabled date is selected).
         }